# 1983 Toyota Pickup Ignition/Starter Problem

Tags: toyota

I own a 1983 Toyota pickup. I left it sitting around for over sixth months. Today the car wont start.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3):

sounds like the starter is stuck...sometimes this will happen when  a vehicle sits... use a large wrench or small hammer and tap the starter it might get the brushes to free up...if not then you'll probably have to have it changed or perhaps dissembled and cleaned